# How to pass a url parameter into the views to be used by other class functions and the template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

Please I have a serious problem that has left me with all kinds of errors for days. There are some functionalities I want to implement but don't know how to. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to create a register form that registers a user and sends them to their profile page after they have registered. I tried doing this by trying to pass the username the user filled in the form into the urls argument for my profile view. However, I don't know exactly how to do this and each code I find online only leads me to error. I am new to django.

In addition to this, I want to create my profile view such that if a user searches their own template, then they can edit it, I used UpdateView for this and if it is not their profile then they can only view it as read only, I used the detailView for this.

Also, please can someone also help me understand how to pass a url parameter into a class based view, how can all the functions in the view access this parameter. How can I use a variable from a function in a class based view in another function in the same class based view. Also is using a url parameter and a redirect the only way to transfer a variable between different views.

Please note that I used a custom user model

this is my current error
[image: current error message]

Error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 172, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 142, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "c:\MouauEasyGo\user\views.py", line 38, in form_valid
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
  File "c:\MouauEasyGo\user\views.py", line 55, in get_success_url
    return reverse('profile', args=(self.kwargs['name_of_user']))
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Elisha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /user/register/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('a', 'g', 'e')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

Below are my codes

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from user import views as user_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/<str:username>/', user_views.profile_update_view.as_view(), name="profile"),
    path('register/', user_views.user_register_view.as_view(), name="register"),
]
```

views.py

```
class user_register_view(CreateView):
    template_name = "user/register.html"
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    model = NewUser


    # I had to override the form_valid method and added form to the self parameter since get_success_url can't access form directly

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.form = form
        if form.is_bound:
            self.kwargs['name_of_user'] = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            data['name_of_user'] = self.kwargs['name_of_user']
        except KeyError:
            return data
        return data

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(name__startswith=self.kwargs[self.request.user.user_name])

    # if the user's username is in slug, then use it in the profile's url else then pick the username from the form and use instead
    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.kwargs['name_of_user']:
            return reverse('profile', args=(self.kwargs['name_of_user']))


# this is the profile page as viewed by the owner of the profile
# the viewer passes the test only if they are the logged in user
# if they are not, then they are redirected to the the
# profile_detail_view.
class profile_update_view(UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['date_of_birth', 'country', 'about', 'image', ]
    template_name = 'user/profile_update_form.html'

    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=user.id)

    # try to get the user_name from the current user.
    # if the user is an Anoynmous user then just redirect to detail page
    def test_func(self):
        try:
            x = self.request.user.user_name
            y = self.kwargs.get('name_of_user')
            if x == y:
                return True
            else:
                return redirect('profile_detail_view.as_view()')
        except AttributeError:
            return redirect('profile_detail_view.as_view()')


# this is the profile page as viewed by the general public
# this view can only be reached if the current logged  in user
# is not the one access the view
class profile_detail_view(DetailView):
    template_name = "user/profile_detail.html"
    model = Profile

    def get_object(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return get_object_or_404(Profile.objects.get(pk=user.id))
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(required=True)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    image = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    about = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ['email', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name', ]

    # save profile info as well as the user info in the form
    def save(self, commit=True):
        if not commit:
            raise NotImplementedError(
                "Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=True)
        user_name = self.cleaned_data['user_name']
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user, created = NewUser.objects.get_or_create(user_name=user_name, email=email, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        user.save()
        user_profile = Profile(
            user=user,
            about=self.cleaned_data['about'],
            date_of_birth=self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth'],
            country=self.cleaned_data['country']
        )
        user_profile.save()
        return user, user_profile
```

models.py

```
class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_superuser(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(
                'Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, user_name, first_name, last_name, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, user_name=user_name, first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg", upload_to="profile image/")
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s profile"
```

Any input will be appreciated. If any other information is required, please let me know. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an example:

Template:

```
    <form method="GET" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="q" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name..." />
            <span class="input-group-append">
                <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
```

URL:
`path('register/', views.register, name='register'),`

View:

```
def register(request):
    name = request.GET.get('q')
    # redirect the page with this information.
```

Reference for implementing [this](https://github.com/addu390/django-pyblog/blob/master/blog/templates/base.html) - Look at the `search` operation performed here.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe it was this easy. Though I solved the problem by logging the user in automatically from my form_valid() method after the form has been saved. Then using a profile url with no parameters  to redirect them to the current logged in user which is the user who filled the form.  I have another profile url that accepts arguments if anyone wants to view another user's profile. This would definitely come in handy. Thanks